Behavior change between EF 6.4 and EF Core 8 in SaveChanges?
I'm currently transitioning an Entity Framework 6.4 / .NET 4.8 app to EF Core 8 / .NET 8. In the process, I have to verify all data transfers to the database.
Context
We have a server application which is responsible for the communication with the database and the communication with the clients. The clients are using a WPF application which receives the data and contains the business logic (which is quite heavy, thus the client which does the work and not the server).
In this context, all data received on the server (send by the client) is disconnected and we have to handle the information properly. In almost all classes, we have navigation properties.
During my tests, I have come across a problem that astonishes me:
I have 2 classes: Batches and Operations. Batches can hold a series of operations and Operations can hold a series of batches. There's other data which is not relevant for my problem. The id, createdAt, etc are handled by a base class called DBBaseElement. Ids are generated by the database.
The simplified classes look like this:
public class Batch : DBBaseElement
{
    public List<Operation> Operations { get; set; }
}

public class Operation : DBBaseElement
{
    public List<Batch> Batches { get; set; }
}

Old Behavior
In EF 6, the framework has created a join-table called BatchOperations which is not visible in the application (neither server nor client). There's no direct reference to that table in the old EF 6 code.
In EF 6, when creating a new operation and linking it with the batches, the id of the operation is 0 while the batch already has an id. When calling SaveChanges on the DbContext, EF 6 would save the operation and replace the 0 id by the newly generated id. Thus, the SaveChanges exits with success.
Transfer to EF Core 8
In order to maintain the connection between the batches and the operations, I had to add this to the BatchEntityConfiguration (I dropped the non-relevant lines of code for more clarity):
public class BatchEntityConfiguration : IEntityTypeConfiguration<Batch>
{
    public void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Batch> builder)
    {
        [...]

        builder.HasMany(b => b.Operations)
            .WithMany(o => o.Batches)
            .UsingEntity<BatchOperations>(
                j => j.HasOne(bo => bo.Operation).WithMany().HasForeignKey(bo => bo.OperationId),
                j => j.HasOne(bo => bo.Batch).WithMany().HasForeignKey(bo => bo.BatchId),
                j =>
                {
                    j.ToTable("BatchOperations");
                    j.Property(bo => bo.OperationId).HasColumnName("Operation_Id");
                    j.Property(bo => bo.BatchId).HasColumnName("Batch_Id");
                    j.HasKey(bo => new { bo.BatchId, bo.OperationId });
                }
                );
        [...]
    }
}

public class BatchOperations
{
    public int OperationId { get; set; }
    public Operation Operation { get; set; }

    public int BatchId { get; set; }
    public Batch Batch { get; set; }
}

I had to do this because EF Core doesn't insert _ between i.e. Operation and Id.
Using the code above correctly loads the data and everything is displayed as should in our client software.
Change of behavior?
This is where the change of behavior seems to occur: in the same situation as described above, an exception is launched when calling SaveChanges. The exception states that there's a problem with a foreign key restriction upon inserting an entry in the BatchOperations table.
I've double checked with the old EF 6 server software that the dataset to save is exactly the same just before calling SaveChanges.
I checked the entries in the change tracker (in SaveChanges), and I see that the data is the same (well, represented differently, but the underlying information is the same in regards to the ids).
EF 6 seems to save the operation, take the newly generated id and insert it into the required place for saving the BatchOperation.
EF Core doesn't seem to do that. It tries to save the BatchOperation with an id = 0 for the Operation.
I counter checked this by first saving a dummy operation, detaching the dummy operation and using it's id for my new operation to store. In this case, the SaveChanges passes because the id already exists and everything is fine.
Questions
Has anyone observed a similar behavior?
Is this the "new" normal behavior of EF Core?
Do I now have to do separate steps to save a graph? (We initially used Graph Diff by zzzprojects which I rewrote for EF Core)
Thanks for your help on this problem.

Look at Behavior Changes between EF6 and EF Core

There are definitely changes. In fact EF Core has no backward compatibility requirements since it is considered brand new "modern" framework. Anyway, to give you concrete answer, please update the post with sample code which reproduces the issue. When working with disconnected entities it is crucial how you put them in the change tracker  (the order and which methods do you use).

@IvanStoev I was aware of the underlying differences of the two frameworks. Hence my rewrite of the Graph Diff lib by zzzprojects.
Giving a complete overview of the source code causing the issue is difficult with the current code base. Multiple SaveChanges occur before the SaveChange that causes the exception.
That said, your hint that the actual order in which the entities are added is quite interesting. That would explain why the save works when I "pre-safe" dummy operations whose ids are then taken to attach the real entities.
I'll create a small code which reproduces the error.

@marc_s Thanks for editing my question to make things more clear by highlighting different words.

Can you add code for that reproduces the issue?
